# why doesn't this program in C language print anything?

Tags: c, char

why doesn't this program print anything?

```
int main(){
    int a = getchar()-'0';
    getchar();
    int b = getchar()-'0';
    int vsota = 0;

    vs = (a+b)%10;
    putchar(vs);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I put in the numbers 7 and 9 and it was supossed to outprint 6 but it does not.

Comment: `6` and `'6'` are quite different.

Comment: @ema Does the program com[pile? For example I do not see where the variable vs is declared.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you try to output non printable character

```
int main(){
    int a = '1'-'0';
    int b = '6'-'0';
    int vsota = 0;

    vsota = (a+b)%10;
    putchar(vsota + '0');
    printf("\n");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/NAyrNn

Answer (score 3):

`putchar(vs);` writes the character whose code is the value in `vs`. The value in `vs` is 6. So it writes the character with code 6. That character is not the digit “6”. You do not see anything because it is a “control character” with no visible appearance. To write the character for the digit whose value is in `vs`, use `putchar('0' + vs);`.

Also, fix this:

```
    int vsota = 0;

    vs = (a+b)%10;
```

That would not have compiled, so presumably you made a mistake when entering code into Stack Overflow. Use the same name in both places.